# WordPress virtual page of a plugin for front end user

Tags: wordpress, virtual

**Hi**,
I have a  WordPress plugin and its have a view page for front end user.Now this view page link is like:
  localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my_plug/plug_page.php

Now i want to create a virtual page for this page and want to page url like
   localhost/wordpress/plug_page

After Googling I got some examples.I was following this tutorial:
 [wordpress-virtual page](http://webstartavenue.com/ultimate-wordpress-development-guide/how-to-create-a-wordpress-virtual-page.html)

Here is my code snippet for this in my plugin page:

```
add_action('init', 'action_init_redirect');

function action_init_redirect() {
  add_rewrite_rule('plug_page/?', 'index.php?my_para=plug_page', 'top');
 }

 add_filter('query_vars', 'filter_query_vars');

 function filter_query_vars($query_vars) {
  $query_vars[] = 'my_para';
  return $query_vars;
  }

 add_action('parse_request', 'action_parse_request');

 function action_parse_request(&$wp) {
  if (array_key_exists('my_para', $wp->query_vars)) {
     get_header();
    echo "I will replace it by my plug_php file";
     get_sidebar(); 
     get_footer(); 
   exit;
   }
  }
```

Is there anything that i missed?? I have tried it my localhost.I saw in terminal it says
**File does not exists localhost/wordpress/plug_page**

Comment: Are you aware of [wordpress.se]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this code running good.I have to called this page like this:
 localhost/wordpress/?mypara=whatever